# What is Rhino.Mocks.Function

Tags: rhino-mocks

Rhino Mocks adds two overloaded Stub methods to System.Object.  One is `Stub<T>(Action<T>)`  the other is `Stub<T, R>(Function<T, R>)`

What (if any) are the differences between `Rhino.Mocks.Function<T, R>` and `System.Func<T, R>`  They both behave the same, but I doubt Ayende would have gone through the trouble to make a new type that did the same thing as a built-in one that already existed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rhino.Mocks.Function and Rhino.Mocks.Action delegates are there to simply allow for compatibility w/ .Net 2.0, which didn't have the Func and Action delegates in the framework.  They both accomplish the same thing.

https://github.com/ayende/rhino-mocks/blob/master/Rhino.Mocks/Delegates.cs